# requirejs get value of returned function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, requirejs, return

I have defined a module called "checkout" which returns different functions like this:

```
define('checkOut',['jquery','require'],function ($,require) {
    return {
    getCheckout: function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/rest/checkout/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
                if(!!res) {
                    checkout = res.data;
                } else {
                    // throwCustomError
                }
            }
        });
    },
    setCheckout: function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/rest/checkout/',
            data: JSON.stringify(checkout),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'PUT',
            success: function(res) {
                if(!!res) {
                    checkout = res.data;
                } else {
                    // throwCustomError
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If I require the module by:

```
require(['checkOut'], function(checkOut) {
    checkOut.getCheckout(); 
});
```

...the getCheckout() function returns an object. But I need the variable "checkout", which should be an object of my response.

The point is, that I need this object in some other modules by calling somthings like:

```
var someVar = checkOut.checkout;
```

or better

```
define('newModule',['jquery','checkOut','require'],function ($,checkOut,require) {
    return {
       checkOut.checkout;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is an async case ... I'd sugegst to chage your `getCheckout` method to not return any value but received a callback; and this callback should be called inside success method from the ajax call

Comment: You are right. By changing `getCheckout()` to a private function and return `checkout: getCheckout()` it works. Thank you!